# Pandas resample: add columns of group_id

Tags: pandas

Consider this resampled series:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=30, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(30), index=index)
series.resample('3T')
```

I would like to add a new column to the original `series` that indicates for each row of the original (non resampled data) to which bucket of the resampled data that row belongs. So for the first few rows of the case above, it would be:

```
                       series    resample_id
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0        0
2000-01-01 00:01:00     1        0
2000-01-01 00:02:00     2        0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3        1
```

because the first three rows are in the same resampled bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `Series` from index and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) first value and then [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=30, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(30), index=index)
s1 = series.index.to_series().resample('3T').transform('first')

df = series.to_frame('series').assign(resample_id = pd.factorize(s1)[0])
print (df)
                     series  resample_id
2000-01-01 00:00:00       0            0
2000-01-01 00:01:00       1            0
2000-01-01 00:02:00       2            0
2000-01-01 00:03:00       3            1
2000-01-01 00:04:00       4            1
2000-01-01 00:05:00       5            1
2000-01-01 00:06:00       6            2
2000-01-01 00:07:00       7            2
2000-01-01 00:08:00       8            2
2000-01-01 00:09:00       9            3
```

Another solution is floor `Datetimeindex` by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) with `factorize`:

```
df = series.to_frame('series').assign(resample_id = pd.factorize(series.index.floor('3T'))[0])
```

Or use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) as alternative to `resample`:

```
s1 = series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3T')).ngroup()

df = series.to_frame('series').assign(resample_id = s1)
```

because:

```
s1 = series.resample('3T').ngroup()
```

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'ngroup'

Comment: Bingo: I was struggling with grouper which was giving me an error. Looking at your code, I realized in grouper you have to explicitly state the `freq`  argument. Thanks for giving all these answers. The grouper one makes my life much easier.

Comment: @user189035 - yes, it is best solution for your problem.

Comment: Nice solution with alternatives and example of why you may want to use `groupby` with pd.Grouper over `resample` in certain situations.  +1